# Eclipse secure storage

Tags: eclipse, password-protection

Is it possible to disable completely the secure storage password of Eclipse? I am running Eclipse Helios on Windows 7.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

To disable the master password prompt you have to specifiy a file containing the password with `-eclipse.password`, see [Eclipse SDK Help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-securestorage-options.htm) and [Bug 241223](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=241223).

The complete procedure is as follows (this is on Linux, on Windows it should work as well if you change the paths):

1. Exit Eclipse
2. Delete the directory ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security
3. Create a text file containing your master password, e.g. `echo "secret" > ~/.eclipse/master`
4. Add to the very top of eclipse.ini, found in the Eclipse program directory (as two lines, don't combine into one)

   ```
   -eclipse.password
   /home/user/.eclipse/master
   ```
5. Start Eclipse again.

Comment: Even it does not disable the feature it is a good workaround (but less secure) to prevent that silly prompt all the time.

Comment: Also, beware of any spaces *after* `-eclipse.password`. It seems to ignore the parameter if there are any spaces after it.

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that in my Ubuntu it always reads /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini (I tried to add ~/eclipse.ini, ~/.eclipse/eclipse.ini, ~/.eclipse.ini) so I would rather not add my password there...

Comment: @Gavriel, you can just run it like `eclipse -eclipse.password /home/user/.eclipse/master` (e.g. modify the desktop entry) without modifying eclipse.ini.

Comment: @FlasHfromRu, probably, but that was a year ago, now I use AndroidStudio and IDEA instead ;)

Answer (score 139):

1. Windows->preferences->then type "secure storage"
2. In the Contents tab, select [Default Secure Storage].
3. Click Delete.
4. Let Eclipse restart.

Comment: A much easier and omho the correct way to delete this. @exo_cw is correct but your solution is better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Agreed. BUT, I just had a situation where on load, Eclipse asked the master password but something was blocking me from input, or closing any windows, or going to preferences. I killed Eclipse, and deleted the directory (@exo_cw steps 1 & 2) and then could get in to delete [Default Secure Storage]

Comment: @User1, your solution worked. Thanks a lot. This secure storage feature was irritating me every time I started Eclipse. Wondering why Eclipse developers added this feature.

Comment: this fixed things for me. yay.

Comment: while this does work, then I can't store any passwords. If you want to store passwords but without having to type the master password every time one of your passwords is used, then the top solution is better.

Comment: when I follow this steps in eclipse neon and restart it, the first thing that pops up is a dialog that asks me to provide a new passwd. I can cancel that dialog, but it appears again whenever I had to provide the passwd also before. Unfortunately not really a solution

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution in Nano.2 on Windows, and it's nice and easy and seems to be working:

- Window -> Preferences -> General -> Security -> Security Storage
- Password tab: in the Master password providers section, uncheck Windows Integration and UI Prompt

I also tried deleting the [Default Secure Storage] in the Contents tab like some other answers suggested, but this is **not needed** and it gets recreated upon restart anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You can now just delete it, assuming you don't need it for anything. Go to Window > Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage and then click on the 'Contents' tab. If you click the Delete button and then restart Eclipse, you will no longer see the pop-up.

From what I understand, Secure Storage is mostly used with repositories like Git and SVN. In my case, I don't need it for my home computer. I use Git at work, but even so, I have never seen the Secure Storage pop up before.

Answer (score 2):

While opening the Eclipse or importing the project, you might get sometimes error called ***Salt must be 8 bytes long***. This is because of conflicts between Java and OS key store.

Either of following are the solutions of this problem.

► Solution 1: Remove file <USERHOME>.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_
storage from your system. After that please restart machine and try to use Eclipse***.

► Solution 2: **Uncheck the Windows Integration (64 bit)** and **UI Prompt** from Password tab of Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage. After that please restart machine and try to use Eclipse.

► Solution 3: Delete **[Default Secure Storage]** from Contents tab of Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage. After that please restart machine and
try to use Eclipse.

Comment: Solution 3 tried and it works for packages from EC Store.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 11.10 with Eclipse Indigo installed the folder org.eclipse.equinox.security is hidden in the /root/.eclipse folder.
Do a

```
sudo su
cd /root/.eclipse
mv org.eclipse.equinox.security org.eclipse.equinox.security.backup
```

Then (re)start eclipse and the password will be gone.

Comment: Do you use the root user to program? :-|

Comment: Why are you suggesting the use of the root user?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it. I only said in my installation it was there. I added the information because I could not find the folder mentioned in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 enerprise 64 bits + java 8
In eclipse go to :

```
Preferences
--> General
    -> security
        -> secure Storage. 
            In master Password providers UNCKECK Windows integration (64 bits)
```

Then go to General  -- network connections -- proxy 
And edit your proxy settings. 
A wizard appear to create Secure Storage