# Eclipse secure storage linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn

Is it possible to disable the secure storage feature under Linux ?
I've tried to delete the folder under **~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security** as well as the content **under window > preferences > general > security > secure storage > content tab**.

However each time i try to use the subversive svn connector, a window untitled user credentials pop up asking me to provide authentication information.

Environment :

- Eclipse 4.5.1
- Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The second answers might to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223059/eclipse-secure-storage

Comment: Thanks Calon, i had a look at that thread already but it seems that the solution is a work around when you want to use the feature. However I dont' want to use that feature at all, i dont want to set a master password.

Comment: I meant the second answer.     Windows->preferences->then type "secure storage",  In the Contents tab, select [Default Secure Storage], Click Delete, Let Eclipse restart.

Comment: Yes I did try this, look at my post

Comment: Oh, sry... well, it is the proposed way. Are you sure that you haven't saved a password for the svn connector? According to this bug, you can only save passwords in teh secure storage thingy in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328682

Comment: Ah yes I did try to save my password however i didn't understood that Eclipse would store it in the secure storage thingy. I thought it was another feature.

Comment: Ok so i did investigated further and it seems that my password isn't saved each time i restart eclipse, it can recall my username but the password is empty

Answer (score 0):

Ok this problem (subversion plugin not saving the password with svnkit connector) does have a workaround described here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464178

But yeah it seems that you have to use a master password if you want to avoid entering password each time you do a svn operation